# Translate serialized nested array string into postgres array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In Rails 5.0, we have a model attribute serialized into YAML strings that take nested arrays:

```
class Foo
  serialize :foos, Array
end
```

If I look at an example of `myFoo.foos` in the database it could look like:

```
---
- - Foo A
- - Foo B 1
  - Foo B 2
  - Foo B 3
```

or in rails it would be: `[['Foo A'], ['Foo B 1', 'Foo B 2', 'Foo B 3']]`

My desire is to create a column migration, moving it from serialized text to be a Postgres Array type.

If it *were not* nested arrays we could do something like this in the migration:

```
change_column :foos, :foos, :string, array: true, default: [], using: "(string_to_array(foos, ','))"
```

But that doesn't work for nested arrays; it'll create a single array with the serialized chunk inside, something like:

```
["---\n- - Foo 1\n- - Foo 2 A\n  - Foo 2 B\n  - Foo 2 C"]
```

Any ideas of postgres function magic that can perform `string_to_array` in a nested fashion? I've tried `unnest` but that doesn't allow you to return a set into a transformation, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: (1) Are you sure you want to use a `varchar[][]` inside the database? I suspect that `jsonb` would integrate better with Rails. (2) How much data do you have to convert? Parsing YAML inside the database is going to be unpleasant.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, I hadn't considered that `varchar[][]` would be bad for the database. We had considered `jsonb` but I went with the array type simply because it generally performs faster. But maybe that's not the case for nested arrays?

Comment: The database should be fine with `text[][]`, I'd be more concerned with the PostgreSQL-Rails interface having some issues.  If the performance difference is going to be an issue then you'd probably be better off with separate tables rather than compound column types. I'm doing some handwaving here so benchmark the various approaches with real data and see if the differences are what we think they are and if the differences are big enough to care about.